# iPhone Text entry with completion and DONE button (not search)

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Using iPhone SDK 3.0, I wish to allow text entry with (optional) completion options that appear as typing is occurring, i.e. also allowing freeformat entry. As such I am using a UISearchBar (which has the text change events) and a UISearchDisplayController to present options.

The problems is I want the DONE button to say DONE and not SEARCH, however I cannot find a way to set that. Clearly I feel I am missing something, or Interface Builder of the SDK API would have some property to set.

I have seen other apps (in the store) that have achieved the result I want (free format entry, completion, DONE button) so maybe there is an alternative approach I am missing. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+1 For wal's answer, but to be on the safe side, and properly react to possible changes in the view hierarchy in further releases consider using this code:

```
NSArray *subviews = [<searchBar> subviews] ;
for(id subview in subviews) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        [(UITextField*)subview setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just had to implement exactly this and couldn't find any great answers anywhere... so I thought I'd provide some insight.  Stepping through the debugger and digging into UISearchBar it is pretty obvious.  I just ended up finding the UITextView within the uisearchbar subviews and at that point then you should be able to set the returnkeytype on that UITextView once you get a handle on it.

Psuedocode-
UISearchBarObject.SubViewAtIndexOfUITextField.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done

Comment: Hmmm... lame that I gave the answer but didn't get the credit... do people really need the code spoon fed to them verbatim???

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...

NSArray *subviews = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar subviews] ;
UITextField *searchField = [subviews objectAtIndex:([subviews count]-2)];
[searchField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Odd, UISearchBar should support the UITextInputTraits interface like UITextField and UITextView do (it doesn't say it does in the documentation) and thus should have [returnKeyType](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/returnKeyType).  I'd try it anyway.

If it doesn't, maybe one of the objects that UISearchBar uses has this option.